# Debug Components in an Org With LWS Enabled - breakpoints not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript-debugging, lightning-web-security, lws

The new `Lightning Web Security` model that is set to overtake `Lightning Locker` is not working the way [the SF docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_lwsec) explain. **In short: I do not have an 'lws' folder.**

From developer.salesforce.com:

> When your components run in an org where Lightning Web Security is enabled, look for the lws folder near the bottom of the Page pane. Expand the folder and see your component files organized under their namespace folder.
> [image: screen capture from SF Dev Docs]
> Here you see the c namespace and its components on the current page (1). The same compositionBasics.js file with LWS enabled is shown with source mapping (2).

I can only see the source code under `top/components/c` as I show below, but, my F12 Developer tools do not allow me to set breakpoints anywhere

[image: my F12 Dev tools Screenshot]

I feel like it did work breifly at one point for me, but I have to disable LWS to do any kind of debugging currently. Anyone else experiencing this?

---

UPDATE 1:

---

I think perhaps there's something about my home network causing this.

The 'lws' folder does indeed appear as advertised if I debug from my work-provided workstation (I remote into it), but it does NOT work from Chrome or Edge on my home workstation (I turned off my work VPN, thinking it was the culprit, but still no luck)

---

UPDATE 2:

---

Even on my work PC, although the `lwc` folder displays - the breakpoints do not hit unless I put a `debugger;` statement in the script, and even then, it doesn't seem be hitting in the correct spots.

Comment: That is really useful. Thanks for the insight. Have you tried to open a support case?

Comment: We have opened case# 44145374 to seek a resolution.

Comment: There is a thread at the Trailblazer Community too: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000NQjEvSAL

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is also happening to me.

I just throw a debugger; in the js file and from there you can debug on web.

Comment: Thanks Raul. I've been doing JS dev for decades, and had never tried the `debugger;` trick. It does help somewhat.

Comment: This was working last month, something has changed which has broken this functionality. If its a dev org or scratch org then you can switch off LWS and debugging works again

Answer (score 3):

Debugging Lightning Web Components (LWC) on orgs with Lightning Web Security (LWS) enabled is working for non-LWR digital experiences, and "CRM"/internal users.

For LWR experiences there is a bug: [Lightning Web Components breakpoints are not working while debugging Experience LWR sites with Lightning Web Security enabled](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000rCKwA/lightning-web-components-breakpoints-are-not-working-while-debugging-experience-lwr-sites-with-lightning-web-security-enabled). The solution is work in progress.